# Refetch event after adding or updating in Full Calendar Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have this component in which i'm initializing `calendarOptions`

```
    export class calcomponent implements OnInit {
    
      calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        initialView: "dayGridMonth",
        allDaySlot: false,
        contentHeight: "auto",
        initialEvents: this.initialEvents,
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        plugins: [rrulePlugin,dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin, listPlugin,interactionPlugin]
      };

    ngOninit()
    {
    ...
    }

adding event in `addEvent` after that fetching event

addEvent()
{
..

this.getEvent();
}

getEvent()
{
  this.Svc.EventList().subscribe((res) => {

     this.resultres=res;
     calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        initialView: "dayGridMonth",
        allDaySlot: false,
        contentHeight: "auto",
        initialEvents: this.resultres,
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        plugins: [rrulePlugin,dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin, listPlugin,interactionPlugin]
      };

  });

}

}
```

in this case again i have to refetch event and reinitialize the calendar options is there any other way to fetch all the event after adding or updating event.

> Updated:

```
 this.calendarOptions = {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        dateClick: this.onDateClick.bind(this),
        events: this.Events,
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood clearly you want a way to automatically update your events whenever you insert/modify them on DB.

My advice is to use rxjs.
You could set up a stream `events$` that will keep track of the events, and it can be triggered by your saving/updating logic.
Every time your `events$` stream changes, the calendar object will be updated.

Here you can see a [demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uzrs4a?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter).

Comment: Thanks i checked this link https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents they have some refetch event is this possible in full calendar

Comment: @user3653474 you can use refetchEvents if you defined a dynamic event source - e.g. a JSON feed, or something using a custom function, where there is a place fullCalendar can go to in order to find new events from their source. Look at the options in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the link is there any example in angular for the same

Comment: @user3653474 It's not really any different. `events` is one of the calendar options so you can just set it up in your `calendarOptions` like all the others.

Comment: @ADyson Can you pls check updated block in the above question i have added event option also, will i have to give url if i want to give paging functionality

Comment: @user3653474 `this.Events` I assume points to a JS array, rather than a URL or a function? If so, `refetchEvents` cannot work with that. Once you pass the events into fullCalendar like that, it makes a copy of them and they are static. There is nowhere to refresh them from. You need to make a JSON feed, or use a custom function, as I mentioned earlier. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function, specifically.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks Yes `this.Events` is an  array which is filled with data by calling api, like in `getEvent()` in question, only we can use one either function event or event json feed, in both pagination is supported?

Comment: @user3653474 what do you mean by "pagination" exactly? I'm not sure standard pagination really makes sense in this context. What you really need to do is ensure your API only returns events which are relevant to the date range fullCalendar is showing in the display currently. fullCalendar provides these dates when the event function runs, or when it makes a call to the JSON endpoint. This is already explained in the documentation links I provided. fullcalendar will then automatically make another function call/request if it needs more events, to cover a new date range.

Comment: @ADyson I'm fetching event from api which can consists of above 1000 events it is taking lot of time to load all events at once, so it there any way when click on next or previous or changing the view the next events should be fetched based on current active start and end dates in calendar

Comment: @user3653474 I literally just explained to you how that works in my last comment, and the documentation I linked you to gives you more detail. FullCalendar will tell you what dates it wants data for, and you just need to write your API code so that it returns only events which occur within those dates.